# In c#, if I have already declared an array of length n, how can I add another element on to it, making it of length (n+1)?

Tags: c#, arrays

Background on the program: the heart of the program needs to track all other Forms or other elements of the program. To do this, I am using a Form array

What I am wanting to do is take my initially defined array containing 1 element, and increase the length of the array to add a new element whenever a new Form is launched.The trouble I've run into is that I can't find out how to do this without using a second array to store the old array, re-declaring the original array with array.length += 1, looping through to re-add the original content from the second array, then adding the new element. It's heavy and inconvenient since I need to use similar processes elsewhere.

The code I have, which works but is ugly, is this:

```
public class PCB
{
    Form[] Runners;
    public PCB()
    {
        Runners = new Form[1];
        Runners[0] = new GUI;
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .

void NewForm(Form app)
{
    Form[] TEMP = Runners;   //Create my new array equal to the first
    Runners = new Form[Runners.Length + 1];  //re-create the old array, with an additional element
    for (int k = 0; k < TEMP.Length; k++)
    {
        //add the original elements back to the original array
        Runners[k] = TEMP[k];
    }
    Runners[TEMP.Length] = App; //add the final element to the array
```

I hate having to use the loop-structure, as I feel that it can be done cleaner. what I'm looking for is a function similar to the ListBox.Items.Add([[ITEM]]), but for an array.

Does such a function exist, or do I need to continue with my ugly loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list instead:

```
List<Form> Runners = new List<Form>();

...

Runners.Add(app);
```

If you for some odd reason *absolutely* must use an array, then [Array.Resize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is what you're looking for, but a list is **much** better.

Comment: +1, and to note, if there is performance concerns regarding `List<T>` implementation, you can initialize with a starting size.

Comment: This looks perfect. Follow up questions though: If I wanted to call a function that I built in my Form, how would I reference the listed item in such a way to be able to call that function? Or should I post another question for that?

Comment: Found what I was looking for. 'Form gui = RunningCore[0]; gui.[function];'

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you're looking for is a List. A List already does this for you under the hood in .NET. You can do this:

```
    List<Form> Runners;
    Runners = new List<Form>();
```

Now when you add to the list you can do:

```
    Runners.Add(new MyForm());
```

When you want to remove from the list you can do:

```
    Runners.Remove(MyForm);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `List<Form> list` instead of arrays, which can be accessed just like an array and you can dynamically add other elements (`list.Add(new Form(...))`).

It is much more performant than an array and it has other features that can simplify your coding.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use Array.Resize 
P.S. !!! be sure that the references to your array won't be changed.
Here is an example:
using System;

```
class aaa
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] array = new string[10];
        Array.Resize(ref array, 20);

    }
}
```